# How can I get the latest date using Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

Hello I have this query :

```
myObject.objects.filter(id=id, date=date).distinct('start').order_by('start')
```

In my table I have only as fields : `id`, `date`, `start` and `end`. `date`, `start` and `end` are datetime type.

The problem is that I would like to get in the `end` the latest date not a random date when I did the distinct on the field `start`. How can I do this ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: `.order_by('start', '-date')`?

Comment: I mean the latest hour for the end, basically start and end contains the hour, date the date.

Comment: then it is `.order_by('start', '-end')` I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by `end` in descending order as a tie breaker if the `start` is the same:

```
myObject.objects.filter(
    id=id, date=date
).distinct('start').order_by('start', '-end')
```

That being said, if you filter on `id=id`, then it will likely contain at most one record, so it is a bit "*odd*", that you filter on the `id` here.